# Javascript to keep position when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have form in footer of my web (more pages) and i need javascript to keep scroll position of form when php refresh the page.

I tried this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myunction()" value="Send" name="submit" class="submitsub">

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).scroll(function() {
  sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
  }
});


function myunction(){
    $("form").submit();
}
</script>
```

But this script always send position to another page, so page is scrolling without clicking on button.

Answer (score 0):

Because your code does not have check to prevent it on a page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href === 'urlWhereYouWantItToRun' && sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
  }
});
```

Alternate approach could be to delete the value from sessionStorage on a new page load.

You could delete the value on page load by:

```
window.onload = function () {
 delete sessionStorage.scrollTop;
}
```

So, to sum up all the approaches:

```
// Page 1
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href === 'urlWhereYouWantItToRun' && sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
        $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
    }
});


// Page 2, and not on page 1
window.onload = function () {
    delete sessionStorage.scrollTop;
};

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    delete sessionStorage.scrollTop;
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is not working well, if i am doing it right.

Do i have to add url of current file? Must it be full url like wwww.example.com/this.php or just this.php ?

Comment: Please can you tell me how to delete the value from sessionStorage on a new page load ?

Comment: what is the issue that is still happening? you could do on this hook as well. `window.onbeforeunload = function () { delete sessionStorage.scrollTop; return; }`

Comment: All is same. When access new page still keep position from first page.

Comment: Where should i write this new     script: window.onbeforeunload = function () { delete sessionStorage.scrollTop; return; }    ??

Comment: with this script is nothing holding position anymore

Comment: you should add the window.onload in your second page. it wont help if this code is in first page only. i get it onebforeunload will remove the value on refresh. you should add the window.onload method in second page where the page is going to only.

Comment: updated the answer, as to what code should be in page 1 and what on page 2.

Comment: Please can you tell me what do you mean with that url? Maybe that is reason why it is still not working.

Comment: by url, i mean `window.location.href` of any page. you simply can run `window.location.href` on the page and know its url. url is also the address in adress bar